# Customer Registration Custom attribute value not saving in database

Tags: custom-attributes, magento-2.1.2

I was trying to add new custom attribute in customer registration. Field's value do not save in database.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: please confirm the magento version? and name of the attribute and is it a text field?

Comment: magento 2.1.2 version am using. new custom attribute field anniversary_year (Anniversary Year)  date field

Comment: Kindly anyone can help me, am frustrated by this changes. please help

Comment: hi @jeni follow the steps which i have posted and please ask u r doubt if any. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Customer Registration Custom attribute value create in admin and save

**1. Text Field**

**2. Drop Down Field**

**3. Date Field**

**Using** `UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php

namespace {CompanyName}\{ModuleName}\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
/* irrelevant */
#use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
/* add this */
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements  UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) 
        {
            // For Text field
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                    'attribute_title',                    
                    [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'input' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Attribute Title',
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 1000,
                        'position' => 1000,
                        'system' => 0,
                    ]
                );
            $attribute_title = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'attribute_title')
                ->addData(
                    ['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]);

            $attribute_title->save();

            //Add field Drop Down for Yes/No
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                    'is_attribute',                    
                    [
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'label' => 'Is Attribute',
                        'frontend' => '',
                        'default' => '1',
                        'class' => '',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 1000,
                        'position' => 1000,
                        'system' => 0,
                    ]
                );
            $is_attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_attribute')
                ->addData(
                    ['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]);

            $is_attribute->save();

            // For Date And Time field
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'custom_date',                    
                [
                    'label' => 'Custom Date',
                    'type' => 'datetime',
                    'input' => 'date',
                    'frontend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\Datetime',
                    'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime',
                    'validate_rules' => '{"input_validation":"date"}',
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 1000,
                    'position' => 1000,
                    'system' => 0,
                ]
            );
            $custom_date = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_date')
                ->addData(
                    ['used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer']
                ]);
                // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
            
            $custom_date->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the new attribute to an attribute set and attribute group when install or upgrade data:

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var GroupFactory
     */
    protected $groupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeRepository
     */
    protected $attributeRepository;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'anniversary_year', [
            'label' => 'Anniversary Year',
            'input' => 'text',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false
        ]);

        $newAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'anniversary_year')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create', 'checkout_register' , 'adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);
        $newAttribute->save();
        $this->attributeRepository->save($newAttribute);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Walish, I put your code in Customer module setup Install data but field is not created in customer entity table. and i upgrade setupn reindex done also. will it be working?

Comment: @jeni, I updated my code. It's work on my Magento 2.1.7, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Here I am showing you how to create a customer custom attribute using simple steps.

Please follow the below steps using a tool called **"Silk Software module creator**"
**http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php**

**Screen shot:**

[image]

**Step 1:** Create a Custom module by the below screen shot

[image]

**Step 2:** Next select the '**Need to Add Customer Attribute**' option and mention the details as shown in the below screen shot

[image]

**Step 3:** Now Download the module

**Step 4:** Follow the install module steps
        Clear flush cache and check the same in the admin end

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much but its not display in frontend . please help me

Comment: you are welcome let me check and update you